# Update values from one column in same table to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to overwrite values that are found in TYPE1 with values that are found in TYPE2.

I wrote this SQL to try it out, but for some reason it isn't updating:

```
select * from stuff

update stuff
set TYPE1 = TYPE2
where TYPE1 is null;

update stuff
set TYPE1 = TYPE2
where TYPE1 ='Blank';
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4733/17

Any reason why my values in TYPE1 are not updating?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This works for me

```
select * from stuff

update stuff
set TYPE1 = TYPE2
where TYPE1 is null;

update stuff
set TYPE1 = TYPE2
where TYPE1 ='Blank';

select * from stuff
```

Comment: Yep, you're right.  But after running the update statements once, I would run the select statement again... but no change.  Is there a new instance of a fiddle after every run?

Comment: @Keven Yes, each SQLFiddle execution is independent of the previous run.

Answer (score 58):

```
UPDATE a
SET a.column1 = b.column2
FROM myTable a 
INNER JOIN myTable b
on a.myID = b.myID
```

in order for both "a" and "b" to work, both aliases must be defined

Comment: the accepted answer works, but this is is a bit more direct and to the point

Comment: I subtracted a point because this doesn't actually answer my original question.  I wanted to update a value from `TYPE1` with the value from `TYPE2` IN THE SAME TABLE.

Comment: Actually the example above answers the question because the JOIN is done on the same table as the FROM statement, if you look carefully "myTable" is referenced twice. It's just a little more verbose than the accepted answer.

Comment: @mastazi Thanks for pointing that out! I completely glossed over the fact that it was the same table.

Comment: This is the best answer for sure.  This is very useful when you're taking data in a column and manipulating it before putting in another column. For example I'm taking my PART_NUMBER column and removing the dashes from it and placing it in MOD_PART_NUMBER.  Best way to do this!

Answer (score 37):

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_A = COLUMN_B;
```

Much easier. At least on Oracle SQL, i don't know if this works on other dialects as well.

Comment: Yeah, works for SQL Server as well (so your answer is perfectly valid for this question).

Comment: I got error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: This should be the answer. Worked for me. With huge concat of 5 columns into one field.

Comment: worked in postgres. Also it easy to combine with another query like `UPDATE table_name SET column_1 = cast(split_part(column_2, ' ', 1) as float);`

Comment: simple and works

Answer (score 3):

You put select query before update queries, so you just see initial data. Put `select * from stuff;` to the end of list.

Answer (score 3):

This answer about updating column from a part of another column in the same table.

```sql
update T1
set domainname = (New value) --Example: (SELECT LEFT(TableName.col, CHARINDEX('@',TableName.col)-1) STRIPPED_STRING FROM TableName where TableName.col = T2.Emp_ID)
from TableName T1
INNER JOIN
    TableName T2
ON 
    T1.ID= T2.ID;
```

Comment: the safest solution

Answer (score 2):

```
update TABLE_1 a set COLUMN_1 = (select COLUMN_2 from TABLE_1 b where a.ID = b.ID)
```

Comment: `SET or WITH expected, got 'a'`

Answer (score 1):

Your select statement was before the update statement 
see [Updated fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4733/24/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `tbl_user` SET `name`=concat('tbl_user.first_name','tbl_user.last_name') WHERE student_roll>965
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make an operation on a specific column:

`update courses set hours = days * 5`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this .

`Update TableName SET Column1=Column2 where id=id`